# How to delete multiple columns in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

How to delete multiple columns in Excel VBA? I tried:

```
Sub DelColumns()
  Dim col As Range

  For Each col In Range("A:C,E:E,H:S,U:AK,AM:AM,AO:AU,BC:BI,BK:BV").Columns
    col.EntireColumn.Delete
  Next col

End Sub
```

**Update.**
I try to do it on a table which is a show-detail table of pivot table. Is it possible to delete table columns without converting the table to a range first?

Comment: `Range("A:C,E:E,H:S,U:AK,AM:AM,AO:AU,BC:BI,BK:BV").Delete`

Comment: I get a msg `Run time error 1004` `Delete method of range class failed`

Comment: Then something else is a problem - the code above works for me. Are there merged cells in your spreadsheet that might be blocking the deletion?

Comment: No merge cells. I use the code on a table which is shown after double clicking on a pivot table (show details). I have many columns then which I do not need.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the delete method against Range to delete columns.

In your case,

```
Sub DelColumns()

  Range("A:C,E:E,H:S,U:AK,AM:AM,AO:AU,BC:BI,BK:BV").Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: I get a msg `Run time error 1004` `Delete method of range class failed`

Comment: I just executed same code here and it is working fine. Can you please check with one or two ranges and see if any errors coming?