# how to refer to a worksheet in a workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

manage to get to here but cannot delete the columns in the worksheet, can you please help? Sorry, big mess even to post the questions

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() ' DELETE ROWS AND COLUMNS (TRIM FILE)

Sheets("RAW DATA FILE").Range("1:7").EntireRow.Delete

Sheets("RAW DATA FILE").Columns("v" & "x" & "z" & "ab" & "ad" & "af" & "ag" & "ah" & "ai" & "aj" & "ak" & "al").EntireColumn.Delete

End Sub
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: The proper way to refer to another sheet is with `Sheets("your sheet name")`. Another way is `Sheets(1)` with 1 being your sheet number, but I have found that to be unreliable when adding and removing sheets multiple times. You use this as `Sheets("sheetname").Range("A1:A7")` etc.

Comment: No problem, I've also posted this as an answer with some additional info that might be of use to you.

Comment: getting error 13, using below

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() ' DELETE ROWS AND COLUMNS (TRIM FILE)

Sheets("RAW DATA FILE").Range("1:7").EntireRow.Delete

Sheets("RAW DATA FILE").Columns("b:d:f:h:i:j:m:n:p:v:w:x:z:ab:ad:af:ag:ah:ai:aj:ak:al").EntireColumn.Delete

End Sub

Comment: can you please help? do not understand why it does not run completely

Comment: You cannot string columns together like you have tried. This will take the columns B to D (so B, C and D) and delete them, but if you add `:F` it will think range B through to D through to F etc, which doesn't work. If you want all the colunms specified deleted separately use the & like so: `Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("B" & "D" & "F").EntireColumn.Delete`

Comment: tried this way but still not working. Sorry guys, pushing to learn here

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() ' DELETE ROWS AND COLUMNS (TRIM FILE)

Sheets("RAW DATA FILE").Range("1:7").EntireRow.Delete

Sheets("RAW DATA FILE").Columns("b" & "d" & "f" & "h" & "i" & "j" & "m" & "n" & "p" & "v" & "x" & "z" & "ab" & "ad" & "af" & "ag" & "ah" & "ai" & "aj" & "ak" & "al").EntireColumn.Delete

End Sub

Comment: Please don't put code in comments - as you can see it's unreadable. Instead add to your question and add code tags there.

Comment: The issue you have with deleting multiple columns [is resolved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32883041/how-to-delete-multiple-columns-in-excel-vba).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can refer to another worksheet in a workbook, and even refer to another workbook.

Refer to another sheet with `Sheets(` or `Worksheets(`. This can take two arguments, either a sheet number `Sheets(1)`, but I find this unreliable as it sometimes is hard to keep track of the proper sheet numbers when adding and removing sheets. The best way is to refer directly by the sheet name: `Sheets("Sheetname")`. Please note there is a [slight difference](https://exceloffthegrid.com/sheets-and-worksheets-in-vba/) in using `Sheets` or `Worksheets`.

As SJR pointed out there is a third way to refer to sheets with the sheet `codename`. The codename is the name of the sheet displayed in your VBA window. You can get the codename of your sheet with `Debug.Print Sheet("name").Codename`. And you can refer directly to this sheet like so `Sheet1.Range("A:A")` etc.

To make sure you refer to the right sheet within the workbook you have open, and prevent yourself from having your VBA run in another workbook you have open at the same time use either `Activeworkbook.Sheets`, which refers to the workbook which is currently active, or `Thisworkbook.Sheets` which refers to the specific workbook the VBA code is in. You can also use `Workbook("Workbook name").sheets`.

[Some further reading for you.](https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/excel/study/vba-methods/)

Comment: @SJR I wasn't aware of that function, so I've learned something new here after playing about with it. I will update my answer.